# Count of tokens in string

Tags: c#, regex

I am really wondering why the following code returns 1 instead of 2. Any clue? Thanks in advance.

```
string report = "foo bar foo aloha hole hole foo cat gag weird gag strange tourist";
string name = "hole";

int count = Regex.Matches(report, @"(^|\s)" + Regex.Escape(name) + @"(\s|$)").Count;
Console.WriteLine("count is " + c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to learn `Regex`, then cool, disregard this.

Otherwise, `Regex` is overkill for something that's so simple using other methods (like `LINQ`):

```
var count = report.Split().Count(x => x == name);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works exactly like I want. I'll learn something about LINQ, too. Btw, regex are so expensive?

Answer (score 1):

Because the first match consumes spaces around the word `hole`, cannot match the second `hole`:

```
aloha hole hole foo
     ^    ^
```

You'd better to use word boundary `\b` instead:

```
int count = Regex.Matches(report, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(name) + @"\b").Count;
```

Comment: \b works but it counts "hole," "hole" "hole?" as three occurrences of one word which is not very sufficient in my case.

Comment: @iwtu, How about using use lookaround assertions, then? `@"(?<=^|\s)"  + Regex.Escape(name) + @"(?=\s|$)"`

Comment: @falsetrue This works as I wish. I didn't know about lookaround assertions. I'll check it. Thanks :)